# Parsing <first_name>João</first_name> with xml-simple

Tags: ruby, xml, xml-simple

I am using the xml-simple gem inside a rake task to parse the contents of a db dump.  The problem is that the database xml file contains characters like those in the title that causes xml-simple to crash.  Is there a work around to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nokogiri seems to work:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml =<<ENDOFxML
  <test>
    <first_name>João</first_name>
  </test>
ENDOFxML

doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse(xml)
doc.xpath('//first_name').each do |node|
  puts node.inner_text
end

#Output: João
```